# TextArea writing checkbox to drop down menu?

Tags: javascript, java, jquery, html, css

I used this to make it write in the Text box, but instead of checking options I would like to  use a drop down menu, so once an option is chosen it is written in the text box. Also, how can I make it write on a new line instead of replacing the current text?

```
<div class="container" id="form">
     <h2 for="test">test: </h2>
     <div id="test">
        <div class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" value="passed" id="cb1" />
           <label for="cb1">passed</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" value="failed" id="cb2" />
           <label for="cb2">failed</label>
        </div>
        <div class="checkbox">
           <input type="checkbox" value="not required" id="cb3" />
           <label for="cb3">not required</label>
        </div>
     </div> 
     <textarea id="result"></textarea>
  </div>

  <!-- website javascript -->
  <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">
  $('#form').change(function() {

     // test
     var test = 'test: ';
     $('#test input:checked').each(function() {
        test += $(this).val() + ', ';
     });
     var test = test.replace(/,(\s+)?$/, '') + "\n";

     // write the result.
     $('#result').val(test);

  });
  </script>
```

Answer (score 1):

The code you show is good, you only put it in the wrong place the `\n`, it must be placed instead the comma `,` and it would fix the breakline.

For the dropdown is just the same:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $('select').on('change', function() {
         var test = $( '#result' ).val() + '\n' + this.value;          
         $('#result').val(test) ;
    });
});
```

https://jsfiddle.net/y52bxv51/1/